# How to export a Crittercism crash report?

Tags: report, analytics, crittercism

Is there a wat to export a Crittercism complete report about crash?

At the moment from portal I see it's possible to export a report about StackTrace and another one to export the Json-encoded user data but I need a complete report, as shown on portal.

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not available at this time.